# Suspended account after an order was entered(message error EBS Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-ebs

I dont know HOW EBS Oracle is validating this information, i dont know what function or procedure is throwing this error message:

> 'ONTOE_PC_CREATE_VIOLATIONHeader orderReason Please, contact the
>   Credit Deparment'

The problem here is that the customer account was shut down after they set an order for him (entered order).

The package involved is this one: **OE_PC_CONSTRAINTS_ADMIN_PUB** that contains this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE Set_Message
( p_operation           IN VARCHAR2
, p_group_number         IN VARCHAR2
, p_attribute_name       IN VARCHAR2
, p_object_name          IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
   l_debug_level CONSTANT NUMBER := oe_debug_pub.g_debug_level;
BEGIN

    IF p_operation = OE_PC_GLOBALS.UPDATE_OP THEN
        IF p_attribute_name IS NOT NULL THEN
       IF nvl(p_group_number,-1) = -1 THEN
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_UPDATE_FIELD_NO_CONDN');
       ELSE
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_UPDATE_FIELD_VIOLATION');
       END IF;
        FND_MESSAGE.SET_TOKEN('ATTRIBUTE',p_attribute_name);
    ELSE
       IF nvl(p_group_number,-1) = -1 THEN
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_UPDATE_NO_CONDN');
       ELSE
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_UPDATE_VIOLATION');
       END IF;
       FND_MESSAGE.SET_TOKEN('OBJECT',p_object_name);
        END IF;
    ELSIF p_operation = OE_PC_GLOBALS.CREATE_OP THEN
       IF nvl(p_group_number,-1) = -1 THEN
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_CREATE_NO_CONDN');
       ELSE
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_CREATE_VIOLATION');
       END IF;
       FND_MESSAGE.SET_TOKEN('OBJECT',p_object_name);
    ELSIF p_operation = OE_PC_GLOBALS.DELETE_OP THEN
       IF nvl(p_group_number,-1) = -1 THEN
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_DELETE_NO_CONDN');
       ELSE
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_DELETE_VIOLATION');
       END IF;
       FND_MESSAGE.SET_TOKEN('OBJECT',p_object_name);
    ELSIF p_operation = OE_PC_GLOBALS.CANCEL_OP THEN
       IF nvl(p_group_number,-1) = -1 THEN
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_CANCEL_NO_CONDN');
       ELSE
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_CANCEL_VIOLATION');
       END IF;
       FND_MESSAGE.SET_TOKEN('OBJECT',p_object_name);
    ELSIF p_operation = OE_PC_GLOBALS.SPLIT_OP THEN
       IF nvl(p_group_number,-1) = -1 THEN
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_SPLIT_NO_CONDN');
       ELSE
         FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ONT','OE_PC_SPLIT_VIOLATION');
       END IF;
       FND_MESSAGE.SET_TOKEN('OBJECT',p_object_name);
    END IF;

END Set_Message;
```

Take a look at this image (i cannot upload images yet):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBVUz.jpg)

**Could you please explain me HOW this function is called? at what stage? I mean, remember that the order was set and then they suspended the account number.**

Also, i was not able to find the other part of the message: "Header orderReason Please, contact the Credit Deparment'". Why? Where is it stored? I think it is a concatenated message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a programming question, since it has to do with the functionality of the Oracle E-Business Suite.  I hope I am not breaking some SO rule by answering.

Your error is coming from a "processing constraint".  You can find these defined under the Order Management Super User responsibility, menu **Setup->Rules->Security->Processing Constraints**.  You will find that message you are seeing there as well, as part of the constraint definition.

The constraints defined in that screen are compiled by Oracle EBS into PL/SQL packages named like 'OE_%PC%'.  They are called from the Order Management **Process Order API** -- basically whenever a sales order or RMA is created, updated, deleted, or cancelled in the applications.